# Laravel base table or view not found in Direct Admin

Tags: laravel, github

I installed the Laravel app for DirectAdmin and I uploaded my project to the server but when I view it on my domain, I get an error message saying:

```
ERRORLOG
[12:41:39] LOG.error: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'captaina_slotsystem.events' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `events` where `endEvent` > 2021-10-18 12:41:39 and `is_online` = 1 and `show_on_homepage` = 1 order by `startEvent` asc) {"exception":{"errorInfo":["42S02",1146,"Table 'captaina_slotsystem.events' doesn't exist"]}}
```

When I run the project using XAMPP on my PC, it runs completely fine so I'm not sure why I am getting the error. My .env file is configured to the MySQL database and I think everything copied in correctly so I'm not sure why on my PC it runs fine but the same files in DirectAdmin lead to this error.

Can this error happen due to a wrong database entry or maybe it's something to do with DirectAdmin but I'm not sure as it runs fine on my PC.

Here is my file structure. [image: File structure]

My database file:

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Database Connection Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
    | to use as your default connection for all database work. Of course
    | you may use many connections at once using the Database library.
    |
    */

    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Database Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
    | Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
    | supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
    |
    |
    | All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
    | so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
    | choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => env('DB_TABLE_PREFIX', ''),
        ],

        'sqlite_testing' => [
            'driver'   => 'sqlite',
            'database' => ':memory:',
            'prefix'   => env('DB_TABLE_PREFIX', ''),
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => env('DB_TABLE_PREFIX', ''),
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],

        'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => env('DB_TABLE_PREFIX', ''),
            'schema' => 'public',
            'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        ],

        'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => env('DB_TABLE_PREFIX', ''),
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Migration Repository Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This table keeps track of all the migrations that have already run for
    | your application. Using this information, we can determine which of
    | the migrations on disk haven't actually been run in the database.
    |
    */

    'migrations' => 'migrations',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Redis Databases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Redis is an open source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
    | provides a richer set of commands than a typical key-value systems
    | such as APC or Memcached. Laravel makes it easy to dig right in.
    |
    */

    'redis' => [

        'client' => 'predis',

        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
        ],

    ],

];
```

Comment: Did you run the migrations?

Comment: Did you update the database credentials in the env file ?

Comment: Note that the laravel app should NOT be in the public_html folder. The laravel public folder should be the root folder for your domain. (thats not the problem here, but very important for security)

Comment: @groovy_guy if the credentials are not correct, you get connection error. in this case the tables are not created

Comment: The thing is I did run the migration. But I ran it on my pc and I uploaded the files to the server. Do I need to migrate the files while they are on the server?

Comment: And yeah I did do that based on the server mysql database @Gert B

Comment: Yes you need to run the migration on the server. That way the database will be created

Comment: Oh I see. Do you perhaps know how I can run it while on the server? I couldn’t find the option so that’s why I thought I could migrate on my pc but obviously that didn’t work

Comment: The same way you run them locally: with the artisan command (you need to connect with SSH and run the command in the applications root folder)

Comment: Got it. So I can use command prompt or power shell and just ssh to the server and then cd to my project folder I assume. Thanks for the help.